# Rounding numbers in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, rounding

I have a program in python 3.4 that prints some numbers in a dictionary, but the numbers are have long decimal places. How do I get it to print the dictionary with no decimal places?

Comment: What are your rounding rules? Should 1.5 be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `int()` if you want just to chop off the decimals or `round()` if you want to round it to the closer number given the precision, i.e. `round(2.456,1)=2.5` and `round(2.456,0)=2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `int`:

```
for k, v in your_dict.items():
    print (k, int(v))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> int(1.000000000000000001)
1
```

or [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> x = 1.000000000000000001
>>> print "{:.0f}".format(x)
1
>>> print format(x,'.0f')
1
```

Comment: I would use round instead of an int cast.  If he had something like 1.9999999999 in there and you used an int cast, it would return 1, when he likely wants 2.

Comment: @BenjaminCohen Only thing OP mentioned in the question was how to print with *"no decimal places"*.

Comment: I know the round function, but I cant get it work with dictionary's

Comment: @PythoN00b post your dict in question body and also expected output.

Comment: @PythoN00b In the question body, not in the comments. Code in comments is hardly readbale.

Comment: When the attack is lowerd by 7% it's a decimal number and I want to print all the players stats rounded off

Comment: @PythoN00b This is the third time I am going to tell you the same thing: post your requirements in question body and also post some sample data with expected output.